# Error: Argument of \\cventry has an extra }

Tags: errors

I've just begun to learn LaTeX and I want to write my CV with it. But there are always some errors and I have no idea how to correct them.

Here's my code:
[image]

and here's the error:
[image]

Actually I downloaded a model of cv using LaTeX. The following part is the original one:
[image]

I tried to write like this:
[image]

and here's the new error:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context to this in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Looks like your missing your 6. parameter?

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! :)                  But What do you mean that I miss 6.parameter?

Comment: Hi Cindy. It could be that the error reported by LaTeX is actually not related to the piece of code you currently display. As such, it's really difficult to address your question in its current form. Update it to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that recreates the problem, *then* we'll be able to help you...